# UNIX C send() errno 14

Tags: c, sockets, pointers, unix, errno

I have this code:

```
void caller()
{
    char buffer[20][20];
    int sd;
    ...
    send(sd, buffer[7], 5, 0);
}
```

Now I have this code:

```
void funct(int sd, char **buffer)
{
    send(sd, buffer[7], 5, 0);
}
void caller()
{
    char buffer[20][20];
    int sd;
    ...
    funct(sd, buffer);
}
```

---

To simplify suppose that instead of ... I have an initialization of socket UDP and connection with the server to use send instead of sendto.
I don't understand why the second code generates on send an error and errno is set with value 14, but the first work perfectly.

Comment: Any warning when you call `funct(sd, buffer);`? You probably get `main.c:24:11: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘funct’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]`

Comment: Can you pass a `char[20][20]` to a function that expects a `char**`? That doesn't look right to me.

Comment: In the first snippet, `buffer[20][20]` and `buffer[7]` appear in the same context, so the compiler knows that `buffer` is an array where each element is an array of 20 characters. In the second snippet, the function parameter is a pointer to a pointer-to-char. That could also be an array of pointers-to-char, but it's definitely not an array of arrays. You *could* declare the parameter as `char (*buffer)[20]`.

Comment: If you're compiling with gcc or clang, you should compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` and you won't have problems like this.

Comment: My compiler doesn't show any warning. @RobertoCaboni

Comment: Oh wow @user3386109. You agree. It works, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Repeat the mantra: "pointers are not arrays"

Comment: @ABC I assume you mean that `char (*buffer)[20]` works. The reason it works is because that declaration tells the compiler that `buffer` is a pointer to array of 20 characters. This allows the compiler to do its address calculations correctly. For example, the calculation for `buffer[7]` is `address = buffer + 7 * 20`. That skips the first 7 rows of the array by moving the address ahead by 140 bytes. In order to do that calculation, the compiler needs the number 20. The declaration `char (*buffer)[20]` contains the information that the compiler needs.

Comment: You could also declare the parameter as `char buffer[][20]`. That may be easier for you to understand and remember. When declaring a 2D array as a parameter, the compiler needs the number of columns (so it can calculate addresses). It doesn't need the number of rows, so the rows can be left blank. You could, of course, specify the number of rows, like `char buffer[20][20]`. But the compiler will simply ignore the number of rows.

Comment: @user3386109 I'm actually not sure the compiler would ever use the value 20 inside the function to determine the pointer arithmetics. See this related answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64042051/11336762

Comment: @RobertoCaboni The question you linked is about 1D arrays. This question is about 2D arrays. With a 2D array, the following function parameter declarations are all equivalent: `char buffer[5][20]`, `char buffer[][20]`, `char (*buffer)[20]`. Notice that I changed the first array dimension to 5 to avoid any confusion about which 20 we're talking about. The compiler won't use the first array dimension (5) in any address calculations. But it absolutely will use the second array dimension (20) in address calculations.

Comment: @user3386109 if I just could find the evidence of what you write in the C standard specification it would be great. There are not many references to "array parameters" in it, and they just say that when a function is called arrays decay to pointers and that parameters are passed by value after assignment-like operations. If what you write is correct there should be something about a special way to pass that 20 to the function...

Comment: @RobertoCaboni That's what the language-lawyer tag is for. Start a new question and tag it with `c` and `language-lawyer`.